# Why is my weekly anacron job not executed?

Tags: cron, anacron

I'd like to use anacron for a weekly job on Ubuntu 13.04.

Here's my /etc/crontab:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 5   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

here's my /etc/anacrontab:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

Here's my /etc/cron.weekly/0anacron:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# anacron's cron script
#
# This script updates anacron time stamps. It is called through run-parts
# either by anacron itself or by cron.
#
# The script is called "0anacron" to assure that it will be executed
# _before_ all other scripts.

test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || exit 0
anacron -u cron.weekly
```

And finally here's the script I put in /etc/cron.weekly/ :

```
#!/bin/sh
curlftpfs -o allow_other,skip_pasv_ip mauro-casa.no-ip.org:21001/Volume_1/Foto/Marta/ /home/mauro/Pubblici/Marta_NAS/
sleep 5
rsync -rlt --update --ignore-existing --size-only --exclude=.picasaoriginals/* --exclude=.picasaoriginals --exclude=.directory --exclude=.dropbox --exclude=picasa.ini --temp-dir=/home/mauro/.rsync-temp/ /home/mauro/Dropbox/Marta/ /home/mauro/Pubblici/Marta_NAS/
umount -l /home/mauro/Pubblici/Marta_NAS/
```

The script is obviously `chmod`ed `+x`, and it works perfectly if executed manually (with `sudo`).

**EDIT #1**

As requested, here's output of

```
cat /var/log/cron.log | grep "Oct 13"

Oct 13 08:29:05 mauro-alienware anacron[1315]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-10-13
Oct 13 08:29:05 mauro-alienware cron[1266]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 13 08:29:05 mauro-alienware cron[1403]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Oct 13 08:29:05 mauro-alienware cron[1403]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Oct 13 08:29:06 mauro-alienware anacron[1315]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Oct 13 08:29:06 mauro-alienware anacron[1315]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Oct 13 08:34:05 mauro-alienware anacron[1315]: Job `cron.daily' started
Oct 13 08:34:05 mauro-alienware anacron[1651]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2013-10-13
```

It seems no logs for cron.weekly is showed.

Instead, here's an extract from `cat /var/log/cron.log.1 | grep "Oct 11"` output:

```
Oct 11 06:47:01 mauro-alienware CRON[12553]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly ))
Oct 11 06:59:11 mauro-alienware anacron[5125]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-10-11
Oct 11 06:59:11 mauro-alienware anacron[5125]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 11 07:45:54 mauro-alienware anacron[5444]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-10-11
Oct 11 07:45:54 mauro-alienware anacron[5444]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 11 07:46:39 mauro-alienware CRON[9156]: (root) CMD (start -q anacron || :)
Oct 11 07:46:39 mauro-alienware anacron[9159]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-10-11
Oct 11 07:46:39 mauro-alienware anacron[9159]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 11 08:46:31 mauro-alienware cron[1249]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 11 08:46:31 mauro-alienware cron[1308]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Oct 11 08:46:31 mauro-alienware cron[1308]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Oct 11 08:46:31 mauro-alienware anacron[1303]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-10-11
Oct 11 08:46:31 mauro-alienware anacron[1303]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 11 08:46:35 mauro-alienware anacron[1839]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-10-11
Oct 11 08:46:35 mauro-alienware anacron[1839]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 11 08:46:37 mauro-alienware anacron[4700]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-10-11
Oct 11 08:46:37 mauro-alienware anacron[4700]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
```

Comment: don't see any cron.hourly  log reports from your output, please, provide full logs somewhere.

Comment: I need weekly jobs to be executed, not hourly!

Comment: they are not written to logs, but exists in crontab, so you missing something or your cron does not work at all

Comment: here you are with pastebin complete cron.log:
http://pastebin.com/gfeGTP4T

Comment: and here you are with complete cron.log.1: http://pastebin.com/9TBQWNbF

Comment: I can find 
Oct 13 10:41:57 mauro-alienware anacron[3033]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated (exit status: 1) (mailing output)
in your log, so you should check root's mail directory for new mail with stdout/stderr of your cron job

Comment: I don't know where/what to search...

Comment: usually it located at `/var/spool/mail/root`
You can read it with command `mail -u root`

Comment: yes, I see... but it is of no help...

Answer (score 18):

You didn't post the actual name of the script you are trying tun run, but chances are it contains a dot ('.'), like if it is ending in '.sh'.

run-parts will **not** run scripts which contain anything else but alphanumerical characters or hyphens. Remove the dot and you are fine.

Comment: And not only does it not run, it doesn't log it in the logs that it didn't run. Wow, not an awesome failure mode. Also: https://serverfault.com/questions/99521/why-would-anacron-not-be-running

Answer (score 9):

## When does anacron run

Usually anacron does not run as a daemon. On Debian based systems it runs with classic cron at `/etc/cron.d/anacron`. It also starts after a system startup, resume from sleep and  changing power management state.

You can check the date when anacron job was last run with `sudo cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.weekly`.

Comment: 20131013...
It seems to be running correctly, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it's looks like updating by 0anacron working, now check /var/log/syslog for Oct 10 for anacron output. You should find something like `anacron[26500]: Job ``cron.weekly' terminated` `anacron[26500]: Normal exit (2 jobs run)`

Comment: why are you asking Oct 10 and not Oct 13?

Comment: @jasmines it's just typo, of cause you should check Oct 13

Comment: Find some output in my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /etc/cron.d/anacron
```

will show you the hour and day when anachron will run, for example:

```
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 7    * * *   root    start -q anacron || :
```

shows you it will run every morning at 7:30 am but only once a week. It checks the date written in

```
sudo cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.weekly
```

(If the date is older, It will start and update the date in that file)

Comment: cat: /etc/cron.d/anacron: No such file or directory